# Set Cookies in Header Field

Tags: ios, objective-c, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am connect drupal with IOS. I m  getting cookies at time of login . Then I am  setting cookie in header in URL request . I am getting Csrf validation failed. Please Help . Any help would be appreciated.

```
appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"%@", appdelegate.cookies);
NSString *post =
    [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"type=%@&title=%@", @"ss", @"ssd"];
NSData *postData =
    [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]]
    forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request addValue:appdelegate.cookies forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[urlConnection start];

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
  [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

  receivedData = nil;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
  [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
  if (receivedData) {
    NSDictionary *responseDict =
        [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData
                                        options:0
                                          error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", responseDict);
  }

  receivedData = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
[request setValue:sessionCookie forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

or

```
[request setValue:sessionCookie forHTTPHeaderField:@"Set-Cookie"];
```

It work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

> You can pass cookie like this
>
> First you have to make `NSArray` of your cookies which is used for authentication like `FedAuth` and `rtFa`.

```
let cookieArray = NSArray(objects: cookie1,cookie2)
let cookieHeader = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(cookieArray)
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = NSDictionary(dictionary: cookieHeader)
```